# problem using python to find_element_by_xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

source code on webpage

```
<a class="btn btn-mini" href="#" onclick="select_all_contacts();; return false;">Select all /a>
```

Using selenium to click button as follows using python on Rpi

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@onclick,'select_all_contacts()')]").click()
```

However get error message  `'no such element' - 'unable to locate element .....'`
What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are missing a wait / delay before accessing this element.
Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@onclick,'select_all_contacts()')]"))).click()
```

Alternatively you can try

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Select all')]"))).click()
```

Also possible the element is inside an iframe.
In this case you will have to swith to the iframe before accessing this element

Comment: both versions give a timeout exception, there is no iframe present on the source page

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: It is the first occurrence of select_all_contacts()

Comment: You did not share the link

Comment: Aplogies seems my answer did not go. I cant share a link as the page is only accessible via  a company password

Comment: I understand, but without this I'm not sure I will be able to help